# Nginx is crashing at boot

Tags: nginx, alpine-linux

I have installed nginx on alpine using "apk add nginx". For some reason when the system starts. Nginx crashes. I checked the logs in */var/log/nginx/error.logs* and this is the output:

```
    2016/07/27 12:54:59 [emerg] 7944#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address in use)
    2016/07/27 12:54:59 [emerg] 7944#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:8080 failed (98: Address in use)
    2016/07/27 12:54:59 [emerg] 7944#0: still could not bind()
```

When I use *sudo netstat -nltup | grep :80*

```
    tcp    0      0 127.0.0.1:80            0.0.0.0:* LISTEN  5264/nginx.conf
    tcp    0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN    5033/nginx.conf
    tcp    0      0 :::80                   :::*   LISTEN    5033/nginx.conf
```

I killed the processes at 8080 using  *sudo fuser -k 8080/tcp*. The ids of processes killed are *5033 5040*. Even after that when I run  *sudo service nginx start*. Gives me this same error:

```
    * Starting nginx ...
    nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address in use)
    nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address in use)
    nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address in use)
    nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address in use)
    nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address in use)
    nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
    * start-stop-daemon: failed to start `/usr/sbin/nginx'
    * Failed to start nginx                                                                    
    * ERROR: nginx failed to start
```

Comment: So you killed the :8080 process but not the :80?

Comment: what OS and control panel you use?

Comment: Check your config in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`

Comment: @ringø there is no folder named sites-enabled. I even tried killing both the processes at 8080 and 80 and did service nginx restart. It still didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Quick fix, if you want to get your Nginx to work for now, but this isn't permanent solution, if you reboot server then again run the same command to get nginx live again.

This will kill PORT 98 process

```
fuser -k 98/tcp
service nginx start
```

Comment: port 98 is troubling from start, so has to be kill the process running by the command first and then restart nginx to get it work

Comment: G    I tried the commands you mentioned above but that didn't work. Getting the same error.